# MSTest: `Unable to load test container` error if nested classes are used in test assembly

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest

Depending on the fact we include one file *.CS in our test assembly or not we get this strange error:

> Unable to load the test container 'UnitTesting.dll' or one of its dependencies. Error
>       details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly x64.Test,
>       Version=7.0.25.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5385d83d2fb4d7d9' or one of its 
>       dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

The error refers to `BadImageFormatException`, something that cannot be issued after adding/removing a *.CS file that contains some unit tests.

After cutting down the critical *.CS file to identify the problematic code, I discovered that the problem is the definition of nested classes. All the *.CS files in the test assembly project without nested classes work like a charm.

Why should I avoid to use nested classes in test assemblies?

Comment: Looks very muck like you have encountered a defect of MS product - you can submit it to [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) website.

Comment: I can't believe I'm the only one.

Comment: Problems might by in how your nested classes are defined or in your build configuration - it might be not quite a common case (otherwise you would have found it with google). I was using *MSTest* couple of years ago with VS2010 and has not seen anything like that. In any case - in MS they will give more exact answer to your question than anybody else.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed splitting unit tests in two groups, the ones using AnyCPU platform target and the other using x64.